# How to change AppIcon and Splashscreen in Titanium Appcelerator?

Tags: android, titanium, appcelerator, titanium-alloy

I am using Alloy framework. I want to know:

How can I change the splash screen and app icon image?

I tried to change the `appicon.png` and `default.png` in `app>assets>android` folder but it didn't work and new ERROR appeared Package build failed.

Comment: Refer this http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Icons_and_Splash_Screens

Comment: you should also change the images in the folders like `drawable-hdpi/`, `drawable-xhdpi/`.. etc too, as Suraj also referred to the link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As suggested you should check [the documentation](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Icons_and_Splash_Screens). It actually describes everything involved pretty well.

Then I suggest that you use [TiCons by Fokke Zandbergen](http://ticons.fokkezb.nl) to generate the splash screens. It's a very handy service :-)

/John

Comment: Awesome service! Thanks for the link!